# upper hemicontinuous (uhc)

Tags: calculus

I want an idea to prove whether
$$
f(x_1)=g(x_1)-a E[\max\{x_1,x_2\}]-bE[\max\{x_1-c,0\}]
$$
is **uhc** (continuous) in $x_1$ and $x_2$ given that $g(x_1)$ is strictly concave and $a$, $b$, and $c$ are constants. Please offer some suggestions.

Comment: Yes. These tags make a lot of sense.

Comment: Is there a difference between "hemicontinuity" and what is usually called "semicontinuity"?  "Hemi-" is to "semi-" as "hexa-" to "sexa-" and "hyper-" to "super-" and "hypo-" to "sub-", etc.: the first is Greek and the second Latin.  Latin seems to fit better with a word like "continuous".

Comment: @MichaelHardy [Upper hemicontinuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemicontinuity) is a notion of continuity for set-valued mappings or correspondences. People sometimes use *semicontinuous* for the same concepz, semicontinuous is ambigous, since it might refer to a weakened continuity notion for functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a function, so continuity and upper hemicontinuity coincide. This function is easily seen to be continuous, once one uses the [nontrivial fact](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Convex_or_Concave_Function_is_Continuous) that a concave function defined on an open interval is also continuous on that interval and the fact that the max-function is continuous.